# Sequelize Association Error include.model.getTableName is not a function

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

Hello I am new to nodejs and currently I integrated Sequelize with NodeJs. I make different models and define associations but when I fetch data then I received following error

> TypeError: include.model.getTableName is not a function

My Box Model

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const PostBox = require("./PostBox");
module.exports = function (sequelize) {
    var Box = sequelize.define('box', {
        id: {
            type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
            primaryKey: true,
            autoIncrement: true,
            references: {
                model: PostBox,
                key: "box_id" // this is the `posts.post_id` column - name it according to your posts table definition (the one defined in ./Post)
            }
        }
    }, {timestamp: false});
    Box.associate = function (models) {
        Box.hasMany(models.PostBox, {targetKey: 'user_posts_id',foreginkey: 'id'});
    };
    return Box;
};
```

Post Box Model

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');

var Post = require('./Post');

module.exports = function (sequelize) {
    var PostBox = sequelize.define('user_posts_boxes', {
        id: {
            type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
            primaryKey: true
        },
        user_posts_id: {
            type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
            references: {
                model: Post,
                key: "id" // this is the `posts.post_id` column - name it according to your posts table definition (the one defined in ./Post)
            }
        },
        box_id: {
            type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        },
        user_id: {
            type: Sequelize.INTEGER
        },
        post_type_id: {
            type: Sequelize.INTEGER
        }

    }, {timestamp: false}
    );
    PostBox.associate = function (models) {
        PostBox.belongsTo(models.Post, {targetKey: 'id', foreignKey: 'user_posts_id'});
    };
    return PostBox;
};
```

This is my base model from where I am calling associated model

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
var Box = require('./Box');

const sequelize = new Sequelize('store_db', 'root', 'root', {
    host: 'localhost',
    dialect: 'mysql'
});

const User = require("./User")(sequelize);
const PostBox = require("./PostBox")(sequelize);
const Post = require("./Post")(sequelize);

function findOneUer() {
    return  User.findOne({attributes: ['id', 'username']});
}

function findPostById(id) {
    var post = PostBox.findOne({
        attributes: ['id', "user_posts_id", "box_id"],
        where: {id: id},
        include: [
            {model: Box, required: true}
        ]

    });
    return post;
}
module.exports = {findPostById: findPostById};
```

When I call **findPostById(2)** method from my base mode then I received this error.

Comment: Did you figure this out? I'm having the same issue only I'm using belongsToMany both directions.

Comment: @Kevin yes I have figure out this issue solved it by importing all models in BaseExportModel and the define relationships in BaseExportModel File.